# What is the syntax for a function signature which returns an array of struct pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I need a function to return an array of pointers to structs. What is the syntax for this? Conceptually I'm thinking `struct my_struct *[] create_my_struct_table(int arr[], size_t length);` But this does not work. I am not trying to return an array of `struct my_struct` but rather an array of `struct my_struct *`.

Comment: It's not possible to return arrays in C. You will have to think of a different design.

Comment: @M.M Can't I return some malloc'd area of memory which contains multiple structr pointers though and index as an array??

Comment: `struct my_struct **` will allow you to return a pointer-to-pointer to `struct my_struct`.

Comment: Sure, but that would be a pointer-to-pointer to struct, and you'll have to specify the length somehow (either explicitly or with a terminator). It's not clear what you want pointers to structs in the first place, though.

Comment: @the_endian yes, but then you are returning a pointer, not returning an array

Comment: Are you familiar with the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)? What is the problem that you really want to solve? Your X problem.

Comment: You can return a pointer to an array, but you have to specify the size. `struct my_struct (*create_my_struct_table(int arr[], size_t length))[5]`.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot return an array in C.  You can return a `struct` that contains an array (which may be an array of pointers).  You can also return a pointer to an array, which must have a lifetime longer than the function that returns it, such as a static array or one returned from `calloc()`.  If it is dynamically-allocated, the caller must free it once and only once.  Or the caller can allocate the destination array and pass its address as an output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct mystruct ** foo(struct mystruct **arrayOFpointers)
{

    int i =0;
    while(arrayOFpointers[i] != NULL)
    {
        //do something with *arrayOFpointers[i]
        i++;
    }
    return arrayOFpointers;
}
int main()
{
    int n = 10; // size
    struct mystruct *pointers[n];
    pointers[0] = (struct mystruct*)malloc(sizeof(struct mystruct));
    //allocate all other pointers in the array like this

    struct mystruct *processed_Pointers[n];

    processed_Pointers = foo(pointers);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: This somewhat misses the intent of the question. The way I read it, it requests allocation of a *pointer to pointer* to struct in `foo` and the return of a pointer to the allocated collection for assignment back in the caller (as well as taking a pointer to `size_t` as a parameter so the number of allocated struct can be made available to the caller as well.

Comment: I think that is not big thing to worry about, just allocate in foo instead of main and iterate through the array of pointers till you get  null pointer, when you get null pointer your size equals to the counter you increment in the loop.

Comment: Sure, that why I didn't ding for it. The biggest problem you have is *Undefined Behavior* iterating `while(arrayOFpointers[i] != NULL)`. There is no sentinel `NULL` at the end of `pointers` passed as `foo(pointers);`. Further, since `malloc` does nothing to initialize the memory within the block it allocated, `pointers[0]` contains `sizeof(struct mystruct)`-bytes worth of garbage following the allocation.

Comment: Let me test and repost it.